# how to run hive script file in windows command prompt containing space in file path?

Tags: windows, hive, command-prompt

I try to run my hive script file in windows command prompt in below file path but I get error as mention..

Here my code :

```
    hive -f c:\Input Folder\hiveFile input1.hql
Error : Could not open input file for reading. (S:\Input (The system cannot find the fil
e specified))

    hive -f "c:\Input Folder\hiveFile input1.hql"
Error : input1.hql""=="beeline" was unexpected at this time.
```

note : If I run this code without space means, script was successfully executed.

If anyone know the answer, please guide me where could I made mistake...

Answer (score 0):

try using forward slashes '/' instead of '\'